# While using where, Include and Select class in Entity framework, got the error as The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using below code to retrieve the data using Entity Framework.

```
BaseTable service = base.dbcontext.BaseTables
    .Include(s => s.Categories.Select(c => c.Definitions
                                        .Select(v => v.Values
                                        .Where(con => con.Id >= 141)
                                        .Select(com => com.Comments))))
    .Where(s => s.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
```

While running this code i am getting below error.

**An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.**

But If i run the above code by removing the condition(**.Where(con => con.Id >= 141)**), it is working perfectly. Below is working code.

```
BaseTable service = base.dbcontext.BaseTables
    .Include(s => s.Categories.Select(c => c.Definitions
                                        .Select(v => v.Values
                                        .Select(com => com.Comments))))
    .Where(s => s.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
```

But i don't want use working code(which don't have the condition **.Where(con => con.Id >= 141)**) because it is taking almost 10 seconds to execute the query. This working query is taking lot of time because I have lot of entries in **Values** and **Comments**  and this query don't have any condition on these two tables.

Comment: Yet another "filtered include" request. It's been asked millions of times. And the answer is still the same - not supported. It would be good to do some (re)search before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Correct usage of .Include()

```cs
BaseTable service = base.dbcontext.BaseTables
.Include(s => s.Categories)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Alexandr Sulimov. But I want Definitions, Values and Comments tables too. How can i get that?

Comment: Use .Select() example http://rextester.com/USPBG53460